# How to change the time in reports in the list of tasks for the past days?

Tags: bitrix

When in the Task, in the "Time" tab, we change the time manually, it changes. The problem is, when we go to the time tab in the user profile, select the past day - a list of tasks is displayed with time, but unfortunately it has not changed.

What could be the problem?

The box version is installed on the server.

Tried to look for this in the timeman module, but where this function was not found.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.